# Ionic 2 *ngFor - Reading value from list

Tags: ionic2

My list looks something like this:

[image: My listist]

When I do this, it works:

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let draft of drafts">
    <ion-item>
        <h2>
            Report identification code <strong>{{ draft.report.pk }}</strong>.
        </h2>
    </ion-item>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

How do I read the values of items inside **section1**? For example, how fo I read the values of "**reportTimestamp**" or "**reportingFacility**"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting this there are two ways :

1. When you receive this data, you can process it like :

   report.section.section1 = JSON.parse(report.section.section1);//This will convert the string to json and store it in the same position.

Then this data can be received in your html like this :

```
<ion-item>
    <h2>
        Report identification code <strong>{{ draft.report.pk }}</strong>.
    </h2>
    <p>{{draft.report.sections.section1.whateverElementYouWant}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

2. Second method is : If you donot want to process the data, then you can call a function from the html which will process it and return exactly the fields that yu need:

html file :

```
<p>{{ getParticularElement(draft.report.sections.section1) }}</p>
```

In ts file :

```
getParticularElement(sectionString){
    let temp = JSON.parse(sectionString);
    return temp.whateverElementYouWant //return which ever element you want to display in UI
}
```

Comment: I went with the second option but it only worked when i used JSON.parse instead.

Comment: yes JSON.stringify converts json to string and  JSON.parse convert json compatible string to JSON object.